# Fetching an array of urls in chaining mode

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive

I have the following case.

I have an array of 'URL' paths that I want to fetch but not concurrently.

I want to fetch a first URL and when finishes (regardless of the result), fetch the 2nd etc. And I want to present the results in as a series of events in a single Observable.

Can I do this? and how?
My struggles:
1. mergeMap-ing will launch the URLs concurrently
2. And even if do the 1 above, I'm having difficulty to put this construction inside a 'for' loop.

I have tried the following, but only the last URL is fetched.

```
const myEvents: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let finalobs = this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${1}`);
for (let i = 1; i < myEvents.length; i++) {
  finalobs = finalobs.pipe(
    mergeMap(evt => {
      console.log(`Getting: ${i}`);
      return this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${myEvents[i]}`);
    })
  );
}
finalobs.subscribe(evt => console.log(evt));
```

Any ideas anyone?

Thank you in advance

Comment: flatMap could be used

Comment: Thanks Ankit. Actually RxJS has mergeMap which is the same as flatMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  .concatMap(event => this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${event}`))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to achieve a sequential subscription on an array of observables. rxjs [`concat`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html) can help you achieve that. Consider the following example,

```
var observables = [];
Observable
    .concat(...observables)
    .subscribe((result) => { /* do something with the result */},
               (error) => { /* do something with the error response */ });
```